# shell script character escape failed

Tags: java, shell

My JVM parameters are configured as follows:

```
set "JSSE_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JSSE_OPTS%"
set "PATH_OPTS=-Drelaxed-path-chars=^"\"^<^>[\\]^`{^|}"^"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %PATH_OPTS%"
set "QUERY_OPTS=-Drelaxed-query-chars=^"\"^<^>[\\]^`{^|}"^"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %QUERY_OPTS%"
```

However, an error occurred while running this script:

```
There should be no > at this time.
```

Do you have any opinions on this issue?

I want to configure the following parameters through the JVM parameters：

```
relaxed-path-chars: \"<>[\\]^`{|} # 允许特殊字符
relaxed-query-chars: \"<>[\\]^`{|} # 允许特殊字符
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are writing a POSIX shell script here? In POSIX shell, a `set XXXX` would set the first positional parameter of the script to XXXX. See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25) for the meaning of the `set` command.

Comment: Speaking just from a syntactical viewpoint (since your code does not really have much meaning): You are opening a backtick, but don't have a closing backtick. Note that, although backticks are considered obsolete nowadays, they are still honoured by `sh` for  compatibility with old scripts. If you want to use a literal backtick, you have to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, you’re using the ^ character to escape these special characters. However, the ^ character is not a universal escape character in all shells. The escape character can vary depending on the shell you’re using. For example, in Bash, the escape character is \, while in Windows Command Prompt, the escape character is ^.

Comment: This is a bash script

Comment: It does not look like a bash script. It looks like a Windows batch file.

Comment: @wenliangzeng-coder :  Agreed, `%JAVA_OPTS%` is a typical env-var in .bat files. the website https://batsh.org may be able to help you convert to bash. Good luck.